# How to Switch Activities using a Custom ListView Adapter?

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I'm trying to use a Custom ListView Adapter to switch to different activities, but am having trouble doing so, as there is an error that I can't seem to get rid of.

Relevant code
Category Table:

```
public class CategoryTable extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.category_table);

    populateTable();

    goToPreviousActivity();
}

private void populateTable() {

    final ListView mListView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    Category 1 = new Category("  One");
    Category 2 = new Category("  Two");
    Category 3 = new Category("  Three");
    Category 4 = new Category("  Four");

    final ArrayList<Category> categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
    categoryList.add(1);
    categoryList.add(2);
    categoryList.add(3);
    categoryList.add(4);

    CategoryListAdapter adapter = new CategoryListAdapter(this, R.layout.adapter_view_layout, categoryList);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private void goToPreviousActivity() {
    ImageButton btn = findViewById(R.id.backButton);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}

public static Intent makeIntent(Context context) {
    return new Intent(context, CategoryTable.class);
}
}
```

Category List Adapter:

```
public class CategoryListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Category> {

private Context mContext;
int mResource;

public CategoryListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Category> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    mContext = context;
    mResource = resource;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String name = getItem(position).getName();

    Category category = new Category(name);

    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);

    Button catName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnNextTbl);

    catName.setText(name);
    catName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (position == 0) {

                //error -> makeIntent(android.content.Context in AllToolsTable cannot be applied to com.test.test.CategoryListAdapter
                Intent intent = AllToolsTable.makeIntent(CategoryListAdapter.this);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);

            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Clicked2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

}
```

(I commented above the erroneous piece of code)

All Tools Table:

```
public class AllToolsTable extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_tools_table);
}

public static Intent makeIntent(Context context) {
    return new Intent(context, AllToolsTable.class);
}
}
```

I will provide any other relevant code/details if needed.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Intent intent = AllToolsTable.makeIntent(CategoryListAdapter.this);
might be this line sounds  the error. because you need to pass Activity context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> //error -> makeIntent(android.content.Context in AllToolsTable cannot be applied to com.test.test.CategoryListAdapter
> Intent intent = AllToolsTable.makeIntent(CategoryListAdapter.this);
> ```

Your `AllToolsTable.makeIntent()` method requires a `Context` argument. Normally you'd be fine with something like `AllToolsTable.makeIntent(MainActivity.this)` because `Activity` is a subclass of `Context`. However, `CategoryListAdapter` is not.

So you need to get your hands on a `Context` object somehow.

Luckily, the `getView()` method passes you a non-null `ViewGroup parent` object, and all views have a context. So you can replace your intent creation with this code:

```
Context context = parent.getContext();
Intent intent = AllToolsTable.makeIntent(context);
```

Comment: Ah, yes that worked! A simple fix, thanks. I'll remember that for the future.